# Is $C^2[0,1]$ closed in $L^2[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis

We know that $C^2[0,1]$ is a subspace of $L^2[0,1]$ since continuous functions on a compact set $[0,1]$ are bounded and therefore square integrable.

However, we know that if $C^2[0,1]\ni f_n\to f$ pointwise, $f$ need not to be in $C^2[0,1]$, for example, $f(x)=x^n $ if $x\in [0,1)$ and $f(x)=1$ if $x=1$.

So if $C^2[0,1]\ni f_n \to f$ in the subspace topology of $L^2[0,1]$, i.e., $||f_n-f||_{L^2}$, then is $f \in C^2[0,1]$?

Comment: Regarding your example: Note that when we identify $C^2[0,1]$ as its image in $L^2([0,1],\mu)$ (where $\|\cdot\|_{L^2}$ is a _norm_) then we would have $$\begin{align*}f(x) &= \begin{cases}0, & 0\leq x < 1 \\ 1, & x=1\end{cases} \\ &= 0,\end{align*}$$ so $f \in C^2[0,1].$

Comment: One slight thing to note is that $L^2[0,1]$ is the space of almost everywhere equivalence classes of square integrable functions, whereas $C^2[0,1]$ is an actual space of functions - so $C^2[0,1]$ embeds into $L^2[0,1]$ in a natural way, but is not strictly a subspace since it's not a subset. This doesn't hurt your question and is almost always a nuisance that is often ignored, but I mention it because often the mismatch in type often gives the right intuition that objects like $C^2$ and $L^2$ don't work together in any especially nice way.

Comment: $C^2[0,1]$ is **dense** in $L^2[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't seem like it.  Can you visualize a sequence of continuous functions $ f_n $ approaching the step function

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
  0 & x \leq 1/2 \\
  1 & x > 1/2
\end{cases}
$$

This function isn't continuous, but you could have convergence in $ L^2 $.  (Imagine continuous functions with a steeper and steeper transition from $ 0 $ to $ 1 $ near $ x = 1/2 $.)

Comment: But if we choose a line segment to make the functions $f_n$ you mentioned, it's first derivative is not continuous. How do you deal with this?

Comment: Oh, that's funny I didn't see the need to be twice differentiable, but that just means you need to be more careful in constructing the functions.   It will need to be a piecewise cubic, which is somewhat annoying but not terribly hard.  (Edit: this, by the way, is a so-called cubic spline, very prevalent in computer graphics!)

Comment: Or, if you're hard-core (edit, hard-core lazy) and don't want to work with cubics, you can convolve the step function with smooth mollifiers, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier

Answer (score 0):

Let $f_n(x)=0$ for $x <\frac 1 2$, $1$ for $X  > \frac  1 2+\frac 1 n$ ad $n(x-\frac  1 2)$ for $\frac  1 2 \leq x \leq \frac  1 2+\frac 1 n$. Then each $f_n$ is continuous and $f_n \to I_{(\frac  1 2, 1)}$ in $L^{2}$. Since the limit function is not almost everywhere equal to any continuous function it follows that $C[0,1]$ is not closed in $L^{2}[0,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f_n(x) = \sqrt{(x-1/2)^2 + 1/n}.$ Then each $f_n\in C^\infty(\mathbb R)$ and $f_n(x)\to |x-1/2|$ uniformly on $[0,1].$ Hence $f_n(x)\to |x-1/2|$ in $L^2.$ But $|x-1/2|$ is not differentiable at $1/2,$ so certainly doesn't belong to $C^2[0,1].$ This shows $C^2[0,1]$ is not closed in $L^2.$